# How do I INSERT a new row or UPDATE an existing row effeciently?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a 'recently_viewed' table with columns

```
product|user|time
```

However, if a user views a product they have already viewed, it will create a new row. What is the most efficient way of covering this possibility (while keeping the possibility that it is the first time they viewed it)? overwriting the old TIME they viewed it or deleting the old table row (and simultaneously creating the new row)?  I can think of some inefficient ways to do it (querying first to see if it's in the table, but this requires multiple statements), but I suspect there is something far more efficient.

INSERT INTO recently_viewed ...

Sincere thanks for any help. It is greatly appreciated from an amateur.

Comment: Which dbms? mysql or sql-server?

Comment: use `UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value1,column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value;`

Comment: mysql. sql-server was a suggested tag so I clicked it. apologies.

Comment: @latheefitzmeontv but that doesn't cover a new insertion? Is it possible to do both in one line?

Comment: why you need insertion of new row here? just need an update `recently_viewed` table for an user ?

Comment: sorry, I guess I didn't explain it will. will add an edit.

Comment: insertion needed because it could be the first time they viewed it.

Comment: How is a "user view" detected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use define (product, user) as UNIQUE, for example you can set it as the PRIMARY KEY of your table:

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  product INT,
  user INT,
  time DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (product, user)
);
```

(or you can also create a UNIQUE index) and then use an [INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) query:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (product, user, `time`)
VALUES (1, 1, '2015-01-01 10:00:00'),
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `time`=VALUES(`time`);
```

Please see a working example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7ed75/1).

Comment: thanks a bunch. I will probably go with this. Is there a reason why this this is a better option than the if/then syntax used in the answer I marked as correct?

Comment: @ambe5960 this will handle concurrency better. What happens if more than one user (or more instances of the same user) views the same product at the same time? Two instances SELECT at the same time, get nothing, and then INSERT at the same time and one of the two will fail

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether record for user exists in `recently_viewed`,

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM recently_viewed WHERE user = "user_id")
BEGIN
   #UPDATE query
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   #INSERT query
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I would strong suggest using `on duplicate key update`.  This starts with a unique index on `user`/`product`:

```
create unique index idx_recently_viewed_user_product on recently_viewed(user, product);
```

Then:

```
insert into recently_viewed(user, product, time)
    values ($user, $product, $time)
    on duplicate key update time = values(time);
```

Comment: Why would on duplicate key be better than the answer I marked as the correct one?

Comment: @ambe5960 . . . For one thing, `if` is only allowed in programming code -- stored procedures, triggers, and functions.  Your question does not specify that the code is in a programming block.  Second, finding the record and modifying it are done in a single statement, so the other version has race conditions if other threads are modifying the table (unless wrapped in transactions, which are not mentioned).